# Função que exibe os caracteres de uma string que se repetem

Tags: c, array, string, funções

Exemplo: Na string "programacao" devem ser retornados os caracteres 'a', 'o' e 'r'. Fiz da seguinte maneira mas não retorna o que é pedido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIM 30

void repete(char *str) {

    int rep = 0;
    char repetidos[DIM];

    //COMPARANDO OS CARACTERES PARA CHECAR A REPETIÇÃO
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; str[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if(str[i] == str[j]) {
            repetidos[i] = str[i]; //ADICIONANDO OS CARACTERES REPETIDOS NO VETOR
            rep++;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Caracteres que se repetem: ");
    for (int k = 0; k < rep ; k++) {
        printf("%c ", repetidos[k]);
    }
} 

int main(void) {

    char word[DIM];
    char *ptr;
    ptr = word;

    printf("Informe uma palavra: ");
    gets(word);
    repete(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `strchr()` da bilbioteca padrão `string.h` para simplificar seu algoritmo.

A função `strchr()` percorre uma string em busca do caractere especificado e retorna  `NULL` caso o caractere não esteja contido dentro desta string.

Veja só como seu programa poderia ficar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DIM 30

void repete( char *rep, const char *str ) {
    while(*str) {
        if(strchr(str + 1, *str))
            if(!strchr(rep, *str))
                strncat(rep, str, 1);
        str++;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char palavra[DIM] = "";
    char repetidos[DIM] = "";

    printf("Informe uma palavra: ");
    gets(palavra);

    repete(repetidos, palavra);

    printf("Letras repetidas: %s\n", repetidos);

    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/UpbeatRealisticFact)

Se você quiser calcular a frequência com a qual cada caractere aparece em uma determinada string, você pode usar um algoritmo de cálculo de `histograma`, veja só:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DIM      30
#define HIST_DIM 256


void calcular( int *hist, const char*str) {
    memset( hist, 0, HIST_DIM * sizeof(int));
    while(*str)
        hist[(unsigned char) *(str++)]++;
}


int main(void) {
    unsigned char c;
    int histograma[HIST_DIM];
    char palavra[DIM] = "";

    printf("Informe uma palavra: ");
    gets(palavra);

    calcular( histograma, palavra );

    for( c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++ )
        printf("%c = %d\n", c, histograma[c]);

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
Informe uma palavra: programacao
a = 3
b = 0
c = 1
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
g = 1
h = 0
i = 0
j = 0
k = 0
l = 0
m = 1
n = 0
o = 2
p = 1
q = 0
r = 2
s = 0
t = 0
u = 0
v = 0
w = 0
x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/NavyblueLiquidClient)

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa comparar desde o início, basta comparar os caracteres à frente e verificar se ainda não consta da lista de repetições.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIM 30

void repete(char *str) {

    int rep = 0;
    char repetidos[DIM]="";

    //COMPARANDO OS CARACTERES PARA CHECAR A REPETIÇÃO
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; str[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if(str[i] == str[j]) {
                if (repetidos[rep] != str[i]) {
                    repetidos[rep] = str[i]; //ADICIONANDO OS CARACTERES REPETIDOS NO VETOR
                    rep++;
                    repetidos[rep] = '\0';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Caracteres que se repetem: ");
    for (int k = 0; k < rep ; k++) {
        printf("%c ", repetidos[k]);
    }
} 

int main(void) {

    char word[DIM];
    char *ptr;
    ptr = word;

    printf("Informe uma palavra: ");
    gets(word);
    repete(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Outra possibilidade seria ordenar todos os caracteres e contar eventuais repetições.